# 'global name <function in same namespace> is not defined' - why is this happening?

Tags: python, vector, rotation, pygame

I'm trying to do some polygon rotation in Pygame, so I'm doing some dot products and getting radians and applying acos to those radians. According to [this link](http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php/t-707152.html) I should use a clamp function to keep the dot product between -1 and 1. However, I get the following error:

```
d_p = (clamp(self.dot_product(other), -1.0, 1.0))
NameError: global name 'clamp' is not defined
```

They appear to be in the same namespace - this is exactly as they appear in the code. I have tried using `@staticmethod` on clamp() but it stays the same. The only thing that works is to make it an instance method (signature `clamp(self, x, a, b)` but this seems like a bad solution when clamp doesn't need to know about a specific instance. What is the right way to fix this, and what concept am I missing?

```
class v2:
#...
    def clamp(x, a, b):
        return min(max(x, a), b)

    def radians_between(self, other):
        d_p = (clamp(self.dot_product(other), -1.0, 1.0))
        cos_of_angle = d_p/(self.get_magnitude()*other.get_magnitude())
        return math.acos(cos_of_angle)
```

Comment: It isn't clear from your code fragment, but are you declaring the function at module scope or class scope?  If it is at class scope, you will need to invoke it as `self.clamp` (or `ClassName.clamp`) even if it is a `@staticmethod`.

Comment: Ah! The solution was to use @staticmethod along with self. I see.
They were both in the same class.

Comment: Using `self` is right. You should post it as an answer to your own question (so it will be marked as answered)

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean calling `self.clamp(x, a, b)` from within the class, with clamp's definition being 
    `@staticmethod`
    `def clamp(x, a, b)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fix this, you must use `self.clamp()` when using it inside of the class that it is defined in. Otherwise you must use `v2.clamp()` if you are calling it from outside of the class.

The reason it is saying `global name 'clamp' is not defined` is because it thinks that 'clamp' is supposed to be a variable,function, or class in the global scope such as:

```
class clamp(object):
    pass
```

or:

```
clamp="I am a variable!"
```

or finally:

```
def clamp():
    print "I am clamp in a function!"
```

Comment: I needed to put in @staticmethod as well for that to work, but it's still better than making it an instance method. Thank you!